# How to publish a Kafka message from Neo4j 4.3-enterprise

Tags: apache-kafka, neo4j, confluent-platform

I'm trying to publish a kafka message from a Neo4j `4.3-enterprise` server.
Something like:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  'MATCH (u:User {status: 'VERIFIED'}) RETURN u',  
  'CALL streams.publish("test-topic", { name: u.name }), 
  { parallel: false });
```

But it seems to me that the `streams` [plugin](https://neo4j.com/labs/kafka/4.1/) is only available for Neo4j up to version `4.1` and Confluent only offers a `sink` [connector](https://www.confluent.io/hub/neo4j/kafka-connect-neo4j) which allows ingesting data from kafka into neo4j.

Is there a way to publish custom data to kafka directly from Neo4j `4.3-enterprise`?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to use the 4.1 plugin with v4.3?

Comment: My neo4j docker container failed to start when I tried to use the 4.1 plugin with the 4.3-enterprise db, but maybe I didn't configure it properly. Anyway, the plugin appears to be deprecated, so I'd prefer not to use it. https://neo4j.com/labs/kafka/4.1/overview/#_compatibility_between_neo4j_and_neo4j_streams

Comment: I'm not sure what it means by "use Kafka Connect instead". That's what the source code already uses https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-streams/tree/4.1/kafka-connect-neo4j/src/main/kotlin/streams/kafka/connect/source

Comment: A colleague of mine pointed me to this link: https://neo4j.com/labs/kafka/4.1/kafka-connect/#kafka-connect-source-instance . So, it seems the Kafka Connect Neo4j Connector also supports `Source` functionality, but it only works with polling. `Custom produce` is only available in the deprecated plugin according to the 3rd item in the "Pros" list here: https://neo4j.com/labs/kafka/4.1/architecture/pluginvsconnect/#_neo4j_streams_plugin